# Validation Rule for picklist field

Tags: validation, configuration

I am having 2 fields in a custom object.

Pricing_Option__c : (pickList) : 
Values:

Show Price,
Show 1st Discount,
Show 2nd Discount,

My_Discount__c  : (percent)

Here in My_Discount__c I want to use 1 validation that if Pricing_Option__c == "Show 1st Discount: then My_Discount__c cann't be blank

Comment: This is a straightforward validation rule case. Please share what you've got so far, and how it's not working.

Comment: Got it :
AND(ISPICKVAL(Pricing_Option__c, 'Show 1st Discount') , ISBLANK(My_Discount__c))